# Why CustomStringConvertible protocol description being called multiple times?

Tags: swift, customstringconvertible

I have written a struct in iOS playground and want to customize the print format of it.

```
struct Point {
    let x: Int, y: Int
}

extension Point: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
       switch (x, y) {
       case let (x, 1..<10):
          print("y in the range")
          return "(\(x), 1..<10)"
       default:
          return "(\(x), \(y))"
      }
   }
}

let p = Point(x: 1, y: 1)
print(p)
```

The result is

[image]

I cannot understand that even though I called `print` only once but `y in the range` message is being printed 4 times.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. – Wait: Did you try it in a Playground?

Comment: @MartinR really? Because I create a new iOS playground to double confirm, the console prints as I posted

Comment: A Playground displays the values in the right column, therefore calls `description` multiple times.

Comment: My general (free!) advice: If *anything* happens in the Playground which you don't understand, try it in a compiled project instead. Then use the debugger, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a playground, the description of a value may be computed multiple times because it will be shown in multiple places (e.g. on the right).

If you're executing the code in a more controlled environment (like in compiled code or in the REPL in a terminal), you will notice that `y in the range` will only be printed once.

Also you should avoid side effects (like `print` statements) in computed properties.